# websocket + node.js + fallbacks framework

Tags: frameworks, node.js, websocket

What is the best framework to use for websockets + fallbacks.

I actually only know about Socket.IO, what are some others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO is currently the best :)